# How do I stack a RectangleChart?

Tags: plotting

What I would like to do is represent the state of a machine over a period of time using a RectangleChart (or anything else that can do it) . The chart will need to be made up of equally sized blocks that change colour based on the state of the machine (there are 7 states 1-7) at that time.

I've created this chart which is similar to what I want;

```
data = Table[{RandomInteger[{1, 7}], 5}, {i, 1, 20}];
RectangleChart[data, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarOrigin -> Left]
```

[image: Almost what I'm after]

The problem with this chart is my state data is being represented by the height of the bar, not the colour.

What is the best way to get the results I'm after?

Comment: "Possible settings for ChartLayout include "Grouped" and "Stepped".  You will need to revert to `BarChart` if you want it stacked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to use `RectangleChart`, then you can do something like

```
   states = Transpose[data][[1]]; 
 RectangleChart[ConstantArray[{1, 1}, {20}], ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
    BarOrigin -> Left,  ChartStyle -> (Hue[#/7] & /@ states)]
```

or

```
 RectangleChart[MapThread[Style, 
    {ConstantArray[{1, 1}, {20}], Hue[#/7] & /@ states}], 
    ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarOrigin -> Left]
```

to get

[image]

Among many other alternatives, `ArrayPlot` is probably one of the simplest ones to use:

```
 ArrayPlot[{states}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks kguler, I think ArrayPlot is what I'm after.

Comment: @Cam, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.